# How to add stepper layout in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter, please guide me to build a stepper layout.
Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Next time you want to ask something, please write a clear question, and leave out all the fluff like "kindly view it" or "please guide me" -- and especially don't tell people to "respond me as soon as possible"

Comment: At least try something before posting a "please guide me" with no questions...That's just lazy

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Stepper` widget:

```
         child: Stepper(
            type: StepperType.vertical,
            steps: [
              Step(
                title: Text("Create a survey"),
                content: Text("Are you happy with our service?"),
              ),
              Step(
                title: Text("Add Questions"),
                content: Text("No questions added"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

For more info, [Flutter Stepper Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html)

Comment: This answer is partially correct. To make it look like the image provided, instead of the "content" property he should use the "subtitle". And to add the custom icons on each step, he should use the "stepIconBuilder".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Column()` with five `Row()` as children. See the following example:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
        Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                Image(),
                Text(),
            ]
        ),         
    ],
)
```

See the excellent flutter docs [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) and [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html).

Comment: i want a full page like this including display grey line

Comment: You could add them by adding a line between the rows. So add extra Widgets in the column between the rows. You have to figure out the positioning.